# How can I obtain the whole min attribute with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to obtain an attribute using XPath.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetTest>
<Result>
<id>10</id>
<name>ABC</name>
</Result>
<Result>
<id>1</id>
<name>DEF</name>
</Result>
<Result>
<id>50</id>
<name>GHI</name>
</Result>
</GetTest>
```

I want now to obtain 2 because the id is minimal in the second attibute. Anybody has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 1.0 the minimum idiom is:

```
$node-set[not(. > $node-set)]
```

> *"Select the node not greater than any other"*

So, to get the relative position you need to count siblings like:

```
count(/GetTest/Result/id[not(. > ../../Result/id)]/../preceding-sibling::Result) + 1
```

Check in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/aab60fddde5c48b013efff791b9f11c9

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest with XPath-2.0.
Try this expression

```
/GetTest/Result[id = min(/GetTest/Result/id)]
```

which selects all `Result` elements with the minimum value.